# creating combinations in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

In R, I have a dataframe defined by

```
foo <- data.frame(variable = c("peltrawl_PF","peltrawl_DF"),low = c(0,3.8),high = c(10,11))
```

I want to make it look like the dataframe

```
bar <- data.frame(peltrawl_PF = c(0,0,10,10),peltrawl_DF = c(3.8,11,3.8,11)).
```

I can do this using this simple case:

```
foo <- foo %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(low, high), names_to = "measure") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-measure)

bar <- expand.grid(peltrawl_PF = unique(foo$peltrawl_PF), peltrawl_DF = unique(foo$peltrawl_DF)) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

But I have to define the variable names which go into expand.grid here, which I don't want to do. This code will be used on a dataframe which is 132x3 which I will be reading in from a csv file, so defining all these variables names in expand.grid is not viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying the actual variable names you can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

foo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -variable, names_to = "measure") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-measure) %>%
  do.call(expand_grid, .)

#  peltrawl_PF peltrawl_DF
#        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1           0         3.8
#2           0        11  
#3          10         3.8
#4          10        11
```

Comment: great answer. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another option in the tidyverse would be a `cross_join` although we'd have to `arrange` the order of rows in the resulting `tibble` to make it equal to the original `bar`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

foo %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -variable, names_to = "measure") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-measure) %>%
  cross_join(., ., suffix = c("", ""))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   peltrawl_PF peltrawl_DF
#>         <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1           0         3.8
#> 2          10        11  
#> 3           0         3.8
#> 4          10        11
```

Data from OP

```r
foo <- data.frame(variable = c("peltrawl_PF","peltrawl_DF"),low = c(0,3.8),high = c(10,11))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: apologies if I'm missing something basic here, but I am getting the error Error in cross_join(., ., suffix = c("", "")) : 
  could not find function "cross_join". I have loaded tidyverse.

Comment: @Fish_Person: `cross_join` was added in {dplyr} version 1.1.0 as a dedicated function.